# MatPlotLib explode largest array value

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, explode

I am creating an array of song BPMs (Beats Per Minute) and would like to explode the largest bpm regardless of where it falls in the array. I am using python and matplotlib, does anyone know to set this up?

example code below

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib 
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

beat = np.array([180,33,46,76,88,222])

plt.pie(beat, explode=explode)
plt.show
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following one liner solution within the plot command itself

```
plt.pie(beat, explode=(beat == max(beat)) * 0.1)
```

**Explanation**

The line `(beat == max(beat))` will result in an array of booleans which will be `True` where the array will have its maximum

```
array([False, False, False, False, False, True])
```

You then multiply it with an explode factor (say 0.1) which will give the following array which you can directly pass to the `explode` argument

```
array([0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0.1])
```

Answer (score 1):

`np.argmax` can find the index of the largest beat. Then this index can be used to set an `explode` factor.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

beat = np.array([180, 33, 46, 76, 88, 222])
explode = np.zeros(len(beat))
explode[beat.argmax()] = 0.1
plt.pie(beat, labels=beat, explode=explode)
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]